# C# Socket: how to keep it open?

Tags: c#, python, sockets

I am creating a simple server (C#) and client (python) that communicate using sockets.

The server create a

```
var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
```

then binds, listens in a infinite loop

```
while (true)
{
    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
    AllDone.Reset();

    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
    listener.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, listener);

    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
    AllDone.WaitOne();
}
```

the `AcceptCallback` calls BeginReceive whose callbackk reads the buffer and sends back a message to the client

everything works. Client sends a message, server sees it, replies, client sees it. But when the client tries to send a message again (for testing client is in a loop), nothing happens

the python client:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host, port))
while True:
    sock.sendall(data)
    blockLen = sock.recv(32) #server sends back a string prefixed with how long the string is
    serverReply = sock.recv(blockLen)
```

how do i keep the socket from dying?

Comment: my opinion reverse server-client language, cos thread and multithreading harder than python.

Comment: that is not an option :( i'd not have chosen different languages if i could avoid it

Answer (score 1):

this is from MSDN([Remarks on EndAccept](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Your callback method should invoke the EndAccept method. When your
>   application calls BeginAccept, the system usually uses a separate
>   thread to execute the specified callback method and blocks on
>   EndAccept until a pending connection is retrieved. EndAccept will
>   return a new Socket object that you can use to send and receive data
>   with the remote host. You cannot use this returned Socket to accept
>   any additional connections from the connection queue. If you want the
>   original thread to block after you call the BeginAccept method, use
>   WaitHandle.WaitOne. Call the Set method on a ManualResetEvent in the
>   callback method when you want the original thread to continue
>   executing.

and there is another question on stackoverflow [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350812/use-of-socket-beginaccept-endaccept-for-multiple-connections).will it be helpful?

Comment: i did not put in all my code but i do have all that was mentioned