# Call beginaccept after error in beginreceive callback?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a windows service C# 4.0 sockets program receiving connects from a piece of hardware, then receiving messages and sending back an acknowledgement

If I fail in my beginreceive callback I find I cannot get another accept callback unless I call beginaccept again.  Is this acceptable error handling?

Not sure if I will exhaust resources

Search in my code for BeginAccept.  Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;

namespace Company.BusinessLogic
{
    public class VconnReceive : abstractReceiveClass
    {
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private InfoSocket infoSocket;

    public override void StartListening(ConnectionsManager.ConnectionConfig configReceive)
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.  
        try
        {
            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
        // The DNS name of the computer  
        //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(configReceive.connectionIP);//ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Convert.ToInt32(configReceive.Port));

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        infoSocket = new InfoSocket(new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp), configReceive);
        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        //available for outside, specifically to close if shutdown
        configReceive.AcceptSocket = infoSocket.socket;

        infoSocket.socket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        infoSocket.socket.Listen(1000);

        // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
        //Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
        infoSocket.socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), infoSocket);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        string strErrorMsg =
            "\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n" +
            "\r\nError in socket startlistening ConfigReceive Connection Name\r\n" + configReceive.ConnectionName + "\r\n";
        log.Error(strErrorMsg, e);
        }

    }

    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        InfoSocket infoSocket = null;
        Socket handler = null;


        log.Info("In AcceptCallback");

        try
        {
        try
        {
            // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
            infoSocket = (InfoSocket)ar.AsyncState;
            log.Info("In AcceptCallback, got socket, config connect-" + infoSocket.config.ConnectionName);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            string strErrorMsg =
                "\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n" +
                "\r\nError in socket accept callback getting socket!\r\n" +
                "\r\nConnection Name not known.\r\n";
            log.Error(strErrorMsg, e1);
        }


        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        state.config = infoSocket.config;

        IAsyncResult result = handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        log.Info("Leaving AcceptCallback, config connect-" + infoSocket.config.ConnectionName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        try
        {
            string strErrorMsg =
                "\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n" +
                "\r\nError2 in socket accept callback!  Config Connection Name not known\r\n";
            log.Error(strErrorMsg, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            { 
            //Do I call beginaccept again?
            infoSocket.socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), infoSocket);
            //close the socket
            if (handler != null)
            {
                try
                {
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                log.Info(e1);
                }
            }
            if (handler != null)
            {
                try
                {
                handler.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                log.Info(e1);
                }
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e3)
            {
            try
            {
                string strErrorMsg2 =
                "\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n" +
                "\r\nError in socket accept callback calling beginaccept!  Interface cannot accept connections!\r\n";

                log.Error(strErrorMsg2, e3);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            }
        }
         }

         return;
    }

    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket handler = null;
        StateObject state = null;
        try
        {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;

        handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket.   
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);


        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            //first check for header only
            if ((bytesRead == 1) && state.buffer[0] == '\v')
            {
            if (ConnectionsManager.ConnectionConfig.StopCheck(Runnable.StopCheckCaller.Socket))
                return;

            state.buffer = new byte[StateObject.BufferSize];
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            return;
            }

            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            //debug purposes
            StringBuilder v1 = new StringBuilder();
            v1.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            //Check for end of file
            string vNewBufferObtained = v1.ToString();
            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
            // more data.  
            content = state.sb.ToString();

            //We're going to split full buffer
            //into individual messages
            string t = String.Copy(content);

            //string[] msgs = Regex.Split(t, "\u001c");//\r\u001c\r\v");
            string[] msgs = t.Split('\u001c');//\r\u001c\r\v");
            bool bCompleteEnd = false;

            //test for partial message, have to exit to get the rest
            //if (msgs[msgs.Count() - 1].Substring(msgs[msgs.Count() - 1].Length - 2, 2) == "\x1C\x0D")
            //the actual check for end of transmission
            if (vNewBufferObtained.Substring(vNewBufferObtained.Length - 2, 2) == "\x1C\x0D")
            bCompleteEnd = true;

            //process the individual messages
            for (int v = 0; v < msgs.Count(); v++)
            {
            //if we're on the last message and it's not complete
            //get the rest by breaking out of here and doing
            //another receive
            if ((v == (msgs.Count() - 1)) && !bCompleteEnd)
            {
                state.buffer = new byte[StateObject.BufferSize];
                break;
            }//last message check for nothing there and if so 
             //break out of here for another receive
            else if ((msgs[v].Length == 0) || (msgs[v] == "\r"))//last record null string or cr
            {
                state.buffer = new byte[StateObject.BufferSize];
                state.sb.Clear();
                break;
            }
            else
            {   //trim any trailing stuff
                msgs[v] = msgs[v].Trim();// new Char[] { '\r', '\v' });
            }

            InfoSocket infoSocketSend = new InfoSocket(handler, state.config);

            Send(infoSocketSend, msgs[v]);
            }

            state.sb.Clear();
            //if we don't have a complete message put what we have in
            //the buffer to concatenate the next time
            if (!bCompleteEnd)
            state.sb.Append(msgs[msgs.Count() - 1]);

            //Set up for next receive
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        }
        else
        {
            //we received zero bytes.  something's wrong. 
            //set up to accept another connection
            //and close the socket.

             //Do I call beginaccept again????
            infoSocket.socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                            infoSocket);
            //close the socket
            if (handler != null)
            {
            try
            {
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                log.Info(e1);
            }
            }
            if (handler != null)
            {
            try
            {
                handler.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                log.Info(e1);
            }
            }
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        try
        {
            try
            {
            log.Error("error", e);
            }
            catch
            {
            string strErrorMsg =
                    "inner error";
            log.Error(strErrorMsg, e);
            }

        //Do I call beginaccept again?
            infoSocket.socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                infoSocket);

        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            string strErrorMsg =
            "\r\n--------------------------------------------\r\n" +
            "\r\nE2 Error in socket read callback!  Interface cannot accept connections!\r\n";

            log.Error(strErrorMsg, e2);
        }

        if (handler != null)
        {
            try
            {
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
            log.Info(e1);
            }
        }
        if (handler != null)
        {
            try
            {
            handler.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
            log.Info(e1);
            }
        }
        }
    }

    private void Send(InfoSocket infoSocket, String data)
    {
        string sProcedure;
        string[] fields = null;

        try
        {
        string strMessage = "test";

        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strMessage);

        // Begin sending the ack or nak data to the remote device.  
        infoSocket.socket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), infoSocket);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           log.Error("Inner error", e1);
        }
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        InfoSocket infoSocket = null;
        try
        {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
        infoSocket = (InfoSocket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
        int bytesSent = infoSocket.socket.EndSend(ar);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        //error handling
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The common pattern is to have the listening socket accepting connections in a loop. The accept call will return another socket on which you receive. You simply close that socket if you receive zero bytes (meaning the other side disconneted) and the accept loop takes care of the rest.

Comment: What if I want multiple receives to happen at the same time? Will what I've done work?  Seems to.

Comment: Move the handler.BeginReceive to end of the ReadCallback() method so it is always run.  You have conditions in the ReadCallback() where handler.BeginReceive() is not being called or you are calling BeginAccept() which is causing issues.  Remove the BeginAccept() from the ReadCallBack().

Comment: the beginaccept at the end of the readcallback is only inside of a catch block.  if i don't call beginaccept again there my process hangs.  calling beginaccept makes it accept new connections okay.

Comment: This seems to be addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350812/use-of-socket-beginaccept-endaccept-for-multiple-connections so I think I may be okay